# Buying games from Steam in foreign store?

Tags: steam

I have noticed recently that Steam has different stores for different countries. These stores generally have different prices for certain games.

Is there anything wrong with me logging into the US store for example if I'm in Europe and paying less for a game? Does this violate the Terms of Service?

Would Steam close your account for such behaviour?

Added tip [SteamDB](https://steamdb.info/) lets you check the price of games in all the different Steam regions.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's against TOS in either case and likely to get you banned from the service.

Comment: Legal advice is off-topic.

Comment: I'm pretty sure they won't allow it, they also check if your credit card and address match the country you claim to buy from.

Comment: This is really two separate questions. Could you please edit your question to only cover one platform, and then ask  a new question for the other platform?

Comment: @Wipqozn Is there any point re-asking the question seeing as it has been closed?

Comment: Closed is a temporary state; it can easily be re-opened in the event you edit it along the lines @Wipqozn suggested.

Comment: @PriestVallon: Your question is fine in it's current state. Originally, you were asking for legal advice, which we don't allow (since we're not qualified to answer those questions). However, it appears someone else has asked a [similiar question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/103126/origin-different-country-purchase) for Origin, so you may wish to answer that question, and convert this one into steam-only so it can be re-opened.

Comment: To clarify, your question is fine in it's current state except that it's really *two* questions, one asking about Steam, and the other Origin. If you narrow the scope of this question to only focus on one of them, it will be re-opened :)

Comment: @Wipqozn Thanks for clarifying. I've edited the question and expanded the answer!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A Steam discussion [here](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=3009074) suggests that buying yourself from other countries isn't allowed and could get your account closed.

What you can do is get someone from another country to gift you the game and they'll only have to pay the amount for their country. Steam has nothing against international gifting.

The [Steam Subscriber Agreement](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=3018240) states the following:

> You agree that you will not use IP proxying or other methods to disguise the place of your residence, whether to circumvent geographical restrictions on game content, to purchase at pricing not applicable to your geography, or for any other purpose. If you do this, we may terminate your access to your Account.

Comment: one question... If I'm from the country X and moved to the country Y. Am I in the risk of having my account closed?

Comment: If you contact Steam Support I'm sure they'll move your account address to country Y and you will have no problems.

Comment: @Michel The issue is where your IP is located. Make sure you have a credit card from that country, too. Otherwise they decline the payment. Also when you move change your address in the profile accordingly and you should not have issues.