# Can games purchased from a North American account be played on a Europe account?

Tags: origin

I am from Europe and I bought something from Origin. What I've seen is that in the USA store the games are the same prices, but in dollars (which makes them cheaper, due o the exchange rate). If I make my purchase from the USA store (giving my account and credit card info to someone in the US) at a better price, can I download and play the game from my computer in Europe?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Buying games from Steam/Origin in foreign store?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/103113/buying-games-from-steam-origin-in-foreign-store)

Comment: Should we really be duping to a closed question?  I'm all for closing questions, but we really should ensure whatever it is we're duping to is open.

Comment: Agreed @fbueckert, this question should be closed as Off-Topic like the one linked to.

Comment: This question is fine; it does not have the same issues as the other question, which was asking for legal advice, originally.  By itself, this is a valid question.  If the other question gets edited to be limited to just ask about Steam, then it also can be re-opened.

Comment: It seems to me like this question is *exactly* like the other. Legalities aside, it is ultimately asking "Can I buy these games cheaper by changing my location?" If this one can be edited to be acceptable, the other one can too.

Comment: It's still a question better asked directly of Origin's support than on this forum. Voting to close.

Comment: @Shadur We don't close questions because there might be a better place to ask; with that logic, Arqade would never be the place to ask questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I can help you, I'm european too and I recently look through that

- First you should know that american price are most of time shown
  "before taxes" so by the time you checkout the price may have
  changed.
- Origin web store always redirect you to your own country store, but I
  guess you already figured that out + for international payement Origin will probably require strong payement verification method.
- There are a lot of better place to acquire cheap priced origin key. You should check [www.allkeyshop.com](http://www.allkeyshop.com)
- Finally through allKeyShop I recently was able to buy Dead Space 3 Ltd. Edition for 28€ and it worked on my EU origin account. Note that incompatibility concerning region lock usually comes with Russian and Asian key. (except for MMO and Battle.net)

After all that I do think that origin american keys would work if accessed through Origin client with european IP adress.

Comment: Thanks for the comment even if it's a bit late. Since then I've discovered sites that sell cd-keys at a cheaper price than Origin and I bought myself what I needed. But thanks for the reply